# How do I enable/disable gravity in a script in unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rigid-bodies

I am making a plane game and want to add a landing but my controller does not have gravity on so I am wondering how to enable a rigid bodies gravity when a certain speed is reached.

Answer (score 1):

What about:
`Rigidbody.useGravity`

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Rigidbody rig;

    void Start()
    {
        rig = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if(rig.velocity > 2)
        {
            rig.useGravity = true;
        }
        else
        {
            rig.useGravity = false;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: im getting this error `Assets\Scenes\PlanePilot.cs(39,13): error CS0120: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Rigidbody.useGravity'`

Comment: Fixed, but this is just a pseudocode. Fix change it to fit your usecase

Answer (score 0):

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.colletions

public class Exampleclass : MonoBahaviour
{
    public Rigbody rig;

    void Start()
    {
       if(rig.velocity > 2)
       {
           rig.useGravity = true;
       } 
       else
       {
           rig.useGravity = false;
       }
   }

}
```